# How to pass epoch timestamp in each requests of Gatling script dynamically

Tags: scala, unix-timestamp, gatling

I have to pass current epoch timestamp in below "request_1" and "request_2" dynamically. How can I achieve this. Below are just few requests given, actually there are many requests in scripts.

Here all requests should have current timestamp only. So each requests will have different different timestamp.

Is there any function so that I can replace all timestamp directly without replacing one by one.

```
  val Transaction_Name_1 = group("Transaction_Name_1")
  {
      exec(http("request_1")
        .get("/abc/details1?_=1590748529401"))
      .pause(5)
      .exec(http("request_2")
        .get("/abc/details1?_=1590748535534"))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to magically do this everywhere. You have to replace each occurrence.

As of Gatling 3.3.1 (current version as of now), the easiest way is to do:

```scala
val Transaction_Name_1 = group("Transaction_Name_1") {
  exec(http("request_1")
    .get(session => "/abc/details1?_=" + System.currentTimeMillis()))
  .pause(5)
  .exec(http("request_2")
    .get(session => "/abc/details1?_=" + System.currentTimeMillis()))
}
```

In Gatling 3.4.0, we'll be introducing a [new Gatling EL feature](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3895) so you will be able to write:

```scala
val Transaction_Name_1 = group("Transaction_Name_1") {
  exec(http("request_1")
    .get("/abc/details1?_=${currentTimeMillis()}")
  .pause(5)
  .exec(http("request_2")
    .get("/abc/details1?_=${currentTimeMillis()}"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirmation. I was spending a lot of time to get some idea to replace all timestamps at once.

Comment: Thanks, I need one more help...
How can I replace "details1" in "request_2" with correlated value "SynchToken" from "request_1". I am trying to replace with ${SynchToken} but it is not reflecting the correlated value.

`val Transaction_Name_1 = group("Transaction_Name_1") {
  exec(http("request_1")
    .get(session => "/abc/details1?_=" + System.currentTimeMillis())
 .check(regex("""name="SYNCHRONIZER_TOKEN" value="(.*?)"""").saveAs("SynchToken")))
  .pause(5)
  .exec(http("request_2")
    .get(session => "/abc/details1?_=" + System.currentTimeMillis()))
}`

Comment: That's not how things work. You must create a new question, not highjack an unrelated one.

Comment: Thanks, I have created new question for the same. Could you please answer that. Here is link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62113261/how-to-pass-correlated-value-in-next-request-in-gatling-script